# column width never exact

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I want a 1000px wide container with 12 columns seperated by 20px gutters. 
So I entered the exact pixels:

```
$total-columns  : 12;
$column-width   : 65px;
$gutter-width   : 20px;
$grid-padding   : 0;
$container-style: static;
```

I end up with these columns:

```
width: 6.77966% /*(calculated: 67.7833px)*/
margin-right: margin-right: 1.69492%; /* (calculated: 16.9333px) */
```

I am totally out of clues what is going wrong here. I got the feeling I am missing something very basic.

Any insight welcome.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Susy was initially built to manage fluid grids, so that's the default setting. If you want static grids, just change the `$container-style` variable to `static`:

```
$container-style: static;
```

That should do it!

Comment: As you can see, $container-style IS static. Still the given widths are not exact.

Comment: I am using susy with drupal's omega 4 theme. A similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182204/susy-container-style-fixed-widths led me to the assuption something is wrong in the omega implementation. I could actually get it right in here: http://sassmeister.com/gist/7633527.

Comment: perhaps you also have a `$container-width` set? Or maybe the theme does? Try setting that to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my mistake.

As mentioned above I am using susy with drupal's omega 4 theme. I created a separate file _grid.scss which contained only the grid definitions:

```
.grid-1 {
  @include span-columns(1, 12);
}
```

What I did not know was that I had to add the column and width definitions in that file as well. So I always ended up with default settings.

Sorry for the disturbance :)