# susy container-style fixed widths

Tags: susy-compass

I have an issue where susy grids doesn't seem to be applying fixed widths to inner columns. Here is my issue http://sassmeister.com/gist/7633527

What I was expecting is that when I have `$container-style: static` that any inner columns widths would get pixel widths but they don't. If `$container-style: fluid` is set then percentage widths would be applied.

Am I misunderstanding something about how `$container-style` works? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, but in this case you've provided Susy with conflicting settings. Your basic grid settings (`80px` columns, `20px` gutters, and `20px` grid-padding) don't add up to your `$container-width` setting:

```
(12*80px)+(13*20px) = 1220px != 1180px
```

Really, Susy should probably throw an error in this case (and in Susy 2.0 it will). But 1.x was built around the idea of fluid internals, and a container to control the overall width/style. So in 1.x, when Susy can't make the static numbers add up, it simply uses your container settings on the container, and your column/gutter settings to get the right ratio for internal elements.

If you want fully static grids, you need to get rid of your `$container-width` setting. If you want an `1180px` grid, make sure your columns/gutters/padding add up to `1180px`.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. I did think that it could be the conflict of grid not adding up. Getting rid of `$container-width` does resolve my mentioned issue.